# Installing windows 10 works flawlessly, but ubuntu wont woirk

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi

Computer model: dell inspiron 14 3452
Processor: Intel Celeron

The only live USBs that are able to boot are the MBR ones, UEFI set USBs using rufus dont make it past grub. Installing ubuntu or any flavor of it doesn't work because the computer does not detect the operating system in the storage but if its windows, it detects it(not dual boot, I am overwriting the storage with the OS). I tried changing the boot options in UEFI but it doesnt detect anything from ubuntu, but it detects bootx64 from a windows installation. Please help thank you!

Comment: For UEFI just format the USB as FAT32 and extract the ISO to it using, for example, 7Zip. Rufus with the proper settings should work too but if doesn't, forget it.

Comment: Im using rufus to burn the ISO into the USB. I tried 2 different USBs so I dont think my USB is the issue

@GabrielaGarcia Ill try just extracting it

Comment: Have you updated UEFI to latest from Dell? Most Dell need update. Are drives set for AHCI in UEFI?  Is Windows fast start up off? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions  Then use Windows to shrink NTFS partition and reboot so it can run chkdsk.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi  & Dell  Inspiron 3670 UEFI update & AHCI worked
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2412152

Comment: Turns out it only works when secure boot is on. If it is off, ubuntu does not get past grub